# How to change example.com/redmine to example.com for Redmine with apache

Tags: apache, redmine

I installed Redmine-3.2 in Debian with Apache using the following guide: [wiki.debian.org/redmine](https://wiki.debian.org/redmine)
I can access to Redmine with : `example.com/redmine`

**Issue:**
I can't change the url to: `example.com`

**Configuration:**
Redmine is installed in `/opt/redmine/redmine-3.2.0` and there is a symbolic link in `/var/www/html/redmine`
This is my apache configuration file for Redmine:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
Servername example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
<Location /redmine>
RailsEnv production
RackBaseURI /redmine
Options -MultiViews
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try next:
change

**`DocumentRoot /var/www/html/`** to **`DocumentRoot /var/www/html/redmine`**

and

**`<Location /redmine>`** to **`<Location />`**

I am not sure because always use Nginx but You must go to this direction.